# Yarn Workspaces - How can I use ES6 Modules in Node and share code with Apollo Server?

Tags: es6-modules, apollo-server, yarn-workspaces

My yarn workspace is comprised of the following:

- common (Plain ol' Node 14.6)
- server (Apollo Server with Nodemon/Babel)
- web (Create React App)

I can share code perfectly between the different workspaces.

The problem is if I try to use ES6 modules in the common workspace. I add "type": "module" to my package.json and switch everything to ES6 modules. It works as expected in the common workspace, I can access code in common from the web workspace, but I get the following error when starting the Apollo server:

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:
require() of ES modules is not supported...
require() of ... is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /Users/i834619/Desktop/ReactProjects/yws_react_apollo/common/package.json.
...
code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'

Comment: So you're saying it works fine at first, and you get the error only on a restart?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear - I updated the question above. It works fine in all 3 with vanilla Node in common. With ES6 modules, it works fine within common, between common and web, but not between common and server.